# Rails .where statement with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm struggling with a .where statement in an index action.

In my Deals controller, i'd like to list all the deals where the bank of the current_user is participating.

Below are my models :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :bank
end
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pools
end
class Pool < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :deal
    has_many :participating_banks, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :banks, through: :participating_banks
end
class ParticipatingBank < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pool
  belongs_to :bank
end
```

Here is my Deals Controller Index action :

```
def index
        @deals = Deal.all
    end
```

I don't find any way to say : 'I only want to see a deal if this deal has, at least, one pool where the current_user.bank has been added'.

Any idea?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do `inner join` and query joined table for id. You can easily do it in Rails by:

```
def index
  @deals = Deal.joins(pools: :banks).where(banks: { id: current_user.bank_id })
end
```

Comment: Many thanks Marek!! Would it prevent people from accessing the deals they are not granted for (where their bank isn't present?). Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, it should. If you want, you can do some tests in console.

Comment: Ok great :) even if they type the URL of a specific deal?

Comment: It's `index` action, you don't type URL here. But if you want to do this in `show` either, you can do it almost exactly the same.